# How to restore a redis backup in a redis container?

Tags: redis, docker

I have a redis container. I would like to back it up and reimport the backup on another machine in another redis container.

I followed theses steps:

```
# Create the original redis container
docker run --name redis -d redis:3.0.3 redis-server --appendonly yes

# add a key inside it for the tests
docker run -it --link redis:redis --rm redis sh -c 'exec redis-cli -h "$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR" -p "$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT"'
> SET foo bar
OK

# backup this container
docker run --volumes-from redis -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /data

# I now have a backup.tar file on my system and I transfer it on another machine
# Recreate a redis container
docker run --name redis2 -d redis:3.0.3 redis-server --appendonly yes

# restore the backup
docker run --volumes-from redis2 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu sh -c "cd / && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar"

# check if the backup has been correctly restored
docker run -it --link redis2:redis --rm redis sh -c 'exec redis-cli -h "$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR" -p "$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT"'
> GET foo
(nil)
```

The backup is not restored properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i face the same issue. is there any solution for this ? i dont see any accepted answer for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do it.

```
# untar the backup
tar -xvf backup.tar

# create a redis container an mounting the backup as the data folder
docker run --name redis2 -v /home/docker/data:/data -d redis:3.0.3 redis-server --appendonly yes

# test
docker run -it --link redis2:redis --rm redis sh -c 'exec redis-cli -h "$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR" -p "$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT"'
> get foo
"bar"
```

It works but it feels "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation. What I ended up doing was creating another image that does nothing but run the commands to perform a mass insert to a linked redis container. This also plays very nicely with my docker-compose file.

So I have one image named **redis** and another named **redis_data**. The **redis** image runs the Redis server while **redis_data** pipes the data to the linked Redis server.

After a redis based container is started (which I named **redis_1**), I run a **redis_data** container.

```
docker run -d --name redis_data_1 --link redis_1:redis redis_data
```

My **redis_data** Dockerfile looks something like this (trimmed for brevity):

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server

ADD data.txt /usr/bin/data.txt

CMD cat /usr/bin/data.txt | redis-cli -h redis --pipe
```

The host specified with the `redis-cli` call is the alias we specified to the linked container.

The data.txt file has my initial data I want loaded in the appropriate Redis protocol format ([Redis Mass Insertion](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert)).